# How to get data for UITableViewController in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a main View that has a table which has it's own controller. How can I pass an array from the main controller to the table controller? (I use interface builder maybe i need to init the view programatically?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

in your UITableView Controller with

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style passArray:(NSArray*)myArray{
```

And use that to initialise your UITableViewController passing your array in.

Comment: do should I put this? in viewDidLoad in the main view file? the table already shows up (without my data) even without being initialized in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Even using the interface builder, you still need a class to inherit from UITableViewController and hold the UITableView there, right? So, you can pass the array into this class's instance. Then you can use methods like:

```
 – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  required method

 – numberOfSectionsInTableView:

 – tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  required method
```

to create the content for your UITableViewController